# What are the elements of the Cartesian product of a family of sets indexed by an uncountable indexing set called?

Tags: set-theory, terminology

Is it called an infinite sequence instead of any "tuples"? I notice that the terms "ordered tuple" is only defined as $n$-tuples where $n$ is a natural number.

The Cartesian product of the family of sets $\left\{X_i\right\}_{i\in I}$ is defined as the set of all families $\left\{x_i\right\}_{i\in I}$ with $x_i\in X_i,\forall i\in I$. If $I$ is an infinite set, is a family $\left\{x_i\right\}_{i\in I}$ an infinite sequence? I am not sure. A sequence is defined as a mapping whose domain needs to be a subset of the set of natural numbers. A subset of natural number is countable. This limits all sequences (including infinite sequences if infinite sequences are sequences) to be families indexed only by countable indexing sets. But the definition of Cartesian product seems not to exclude the case when $I$ is uncountable.

Then what should we generally call the element of a Cartesian product? "~ tuples" or "~ sequences" seem not correct choices. Shouldn't we use the same noun for all cases, adding only adjectives only for different situations? I think we shouldn't restrict the meaning of the term "ordered tuple" to "$n$-tuple", so that an ordered tuple may or may not contain countable elements. But I am not sure about it.

Comment: I call them functions.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you for the comment. Do you agree that, indeed, we do not have a narrower name for them but only call them functions, given the fact that we have narrower names (tuples, sequences, etc.) for the countable cases even though in these cases they are also functions?

Comment: $I$-tuples is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much @AsafKaragila! I like this name!